# which is correct? Is or Was?

Tags: grammar

Which is grammatically correct:
The letter to xxx is drafted by xxx?
or
The letter to xxx was drafted by xxx?

Comment: They're both "grammatically correct".  They simply mean different things.

Answer (score 0):

If you're describing the letter itself, it *is* a letter that Xavier drafted. So you can use "is" if you wish.

If you're describing the event of the letter being drafted, and it's not happening 'right now' in your story, you should definitely use "was".